# Is it possible to create a Java class object inside a Kotlin class?

Tags: java, android, class, kotlin, object

I have a Java class let's say with the following code :

```
public class Tigers {

private final int weight;

public int getWeight() {
return weight; }
}
```

Now I want to access this getWeight() method from a Kotlin class. How do I do it? More particularly while writing a unit test.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html

Answer (score 1):

Java classes are available for Kotlin out-of-the-box. As you have this class in your classpath, simply go with:

```
val tigers = Tigers()
tigers.weight // calls .getWeight() getter
```